# Istio tracing x-b3-sampled is always 0

Tags: istio, distributed-tracing

I am new to istio, and I am trying to setup the tracing, but can't make it work.
Then I logged the trace headers in my service, I fount that the **x-b3-sampled is awlays zero**

> x-request-id:e1a8e4f3-5256-9e43-b571-a9c8a4c93db7, x-b3-traceid:b2328351dbb2f95fd0ec782c5103f1c1, x-b3-spanid:a6ef2135d03fac8a, x-b3-parentspanid:d0ec782c5103f1c1, x-b3-sampled:0, x-b3-flags:null, x-ot-span-context:null
> This is what the service log printed.

I've set the sampling to 100

```
tracing:
 sampling: 100
 zipkin:
  address: zipkin.istio-system:9411
```

Anyone knows the reason, or how can I work it out?

Comment: you would need to show your code, not your tracing config. how are you handling these headers?

Comment: @suren I did not handle any of these headers, it is the first service which I print those logs, just  `istio_gateway -> my_service`.  That means, `x-b3-sampled:0` is generated by the istio proxy, I think.

Comment: you need to generate these headers and pass from one service to another from your code.

Comment: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation.  **To do this, an application needs to collect and propagate the following headers from the incoming request to any outgoing requests**.  As the document says, I just need to pass it to the outgoing requests,

Comment: `I fount that the x-b3-sampled is always zero`, even in [bookinfo application](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/)? Do you use ingress controller or istio ingress gateway? As per the headers I agree with @suren, when using the Zipkin tracer, Envoy relies on the **service** to propagate the B3 HTTP headers. It's better described in envoy documentation [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/observability/tracing#trace-context-propagation). Also take a look [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/b3-propagation).

Comment: actually, `X-B3-Sampled` is not always zero. Usually it's 1.